# How to describe the graph of wedding guests mathematically?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working with a particular graph problem and I'm not sure how to describe it. I dug up my algorithms textbook and can't find anything exactly right. I'm trying to plot a path through a weighted undirected complete graph where the weight of the path is defined by the 1-to-1 weights between all vertices.

Here's an example. Imagine I'm making seating charts for a wedding. Some wedding guests are good friends and others... not so much. I used an undirected graph with each guest on the vertices and the 1-to-1 relationships between guests as the edges. Here's a graph of the relationships between the guests Amy, Brent, Charlie, and Donald. I abbreviated their names as A, B, C, and D.

[image: First graph image]

Donald caused some drama and has negative relationships with other guests. To maintain harmony, I want don't want the sum of relationships at any table to be negative. Imagine putting Amy, Brent, and Donald at the same table.

[image: Awkward]

The sum of the edge weights between these three people is 5-5-5=-5, which is less than zero. So I don't want this table arrangement. In the past, I've looked at one weight at a time when constructing paths, so this would be a path from AB (+5) that continues BC (-5), meaning the path ABC would have a weight of 0. Here I want to include the edge weight AC (-5) as well.

Is there a name for a path through a graph like this where you have to count the total 1:1 edge weights instead of just the edges used in a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum the edge weights for all pairs of people who are seated at the same table, you are talking about a complete subgraph, which is called a *clique*.  You might also be interested in [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/operations/2014/11/10/do-you-have-an-uncle-louie-optimal-wedding-seat-assignments/), where the objective is to minimize the sum across tables of the maximum unhappiness at the table.